# SQL Server Authentication and Folder Permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

In SQL Server 2014, I have created a login with SQL Server Authentication with which I am trying to do `BULK INSERT`; however it is failing because Windows is not letting SQL Server access the folder where the insert file is.  If I enable Full Control for Everyone the bulk insert works, but that is not an acceptable solution.  Within SQL Server setup, I have tried adding a Credential (with windows authentication that has rights to the folder) to the login, but this didn't work.  I have also tried adding Full Control for users `my_server\SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$WIN-832289876` and `my_server\SQLServerMSASUser$WIN-832289876$MSSQLSERVER` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always struggle with this. For me, allowing MSSQLSERVER full permission to the folder where the input file resides always seems to work.

Right-click the folder (as an admin on the box), go to properties, security, edit, add...

here is where I always get tripped up. For me, the server service account is "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER" and I can never search for that user. I have to type it in manually and check the name to make sure I typed it in correctly. For you, this may not be the service account used by your server. Check your services list from windows administrative tools to see what account is in "Log On As" for SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER).

Comment: Thanks! Not being able to search for the name is what tripped me :(